# flutter cameracontrol.takepicture can not work with provided file path

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, dart

I created a simple flutter app, the app has functionality that could take picture or video with CameraController, and after take picture or video then save the picture or video to a provided file path. 
I write some code as following, as you can see I just give a fixed path "/storage/emulated/0/gang" which I am going to use as path to store all the pictures. And I will read these picture from the path. But the app report error "save image failed".

```
...
final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
final String filePath = '/storage/0/user/gang/${currentTime}.jpg';

try {
  await controller.takePicture(filePath);
} on CameraException catch (e) {
  _showCameraException(e);
  return null;
}
...
```

It does work with the "ApplicationDocumentsDirectory", but as I understand, it is a temporary directory, I will use the path as my picture/video persisting location, so I do not wanna to use it.

```
final Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String pictureDirectory = '${appDirectory.path}/Pictures';
await Directory(pictureDirectory).create(recursive: true);
final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
final String filePath = '$pictureDirectory/${currentTime}.jpg';

try {
  await controller.takePicture(filePath);
} on CameraException catch (e) {
  _showCameraException(e);
  return null;
}
```

I also tried with GallerySaver, but after import the dependency, my app is totally broken when installing on my testing android phone.

Please help to advice how I can archive my function, I am totally new with flutter and mobile app, any comment is welcome, very appreciate.

Comment: Any comment is welcome!!

Comment: Any comment is welcome!!

Comment: Could you check AndroidManifest.xml with these two permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>